Filtering wp_query
NOTE: Edited, because I was able to turn this into a form and use the GET method.
This is my first time asking a question here, so please bear with me.  I'm new to theme development and truly giving this my best shot.
This theme is specifically for my own website (wordpress/woocommerce).  This class aims to provides filter options based on product attributes shown as checkboxes on product category pages.  So far with the help of no less than a hundred google searches I've been able to create the class below and am require_once the class file in functions.php.
In essence, this class creates a few scrollable checkbox lists that I plan to use to filter category results. Here is what the filter options look like on the frontend.  Well, now that I have created the options for what to filter by and put them in the $_GET global variable, I'm truly getting stuck on how to proceed from here, passing them to a wp_query. I was looking into the pre_get_posts hook https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/ but it suggested:
Unless you are intimately familiar with these settings and are willing to coordinate them yourself, it’s suggested that you replace the main query by using WP_Queryin the page.php or single.php (child)theme template files.
I've found the documentation for wp_query but I am not sure if I need to bring over the taxonomy-product-cat.php template from Woocommerce and create my own query/loop to make this work...and I have no idea how to make the "apply filters" button hook into a new query.  Really, I'm stuck at filtering the results that match.  Any pointers in the right direction or warnings that I am going in the wrong direction would be greatly appreciated.
The checkboxes within one scrollable list would be an OR statement, and each list would compare with an AND statement.  I'm clueless as to the right way to get these applied to a query.
<?php 

if (!class_exists('Ccon_Catalog_filters')) {
    class Ccon_Catalog_Filters {
        function init() {
            add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', [ $this, 'category_filter_menu'], 9, 1);
            add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', [ $this, 'taxonomy_edit_meta_field' ], 10, 1);
            add_action( 'edited_product_cat', [ $this, 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta' ], 10, 1);
            
        }
        function category_filter_menu() {
            $filters = $this->get_filter_options();
            $this->status($filters);
            echo var_dump($_GET);
            ?>
                <form method="GET" class="archive-filter-container">
                    <?php foreach ($filters as $filter): ?>
                        <?php $terms = $this->get_filter_att_val($filter); ?>
                        <div class="archive-filter-item archive-filter-item-<?php echo esc_attr($filter->attribute_name); ?>">
                            <h4><?php echo $filter->attribute_label; ?></h4>
                            <div class="archive-filter-content">
                                <?php foreach ($terms as $term): ?>
                                    <div style="display: block">
                                        <input 
                                            type=   "checkbox" 
                                            name=   "<?php echo esc_attr($filter->attribute_name); ?>[]" 
                                            id=     "<?php echo esc_attr($filter->attribute_name . '-' . $term->slug); ?>"
                                            value=  "<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug); ?>"
                                            <?php $this->checked($term, $filter); ?>
                                        >
                                        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($filter->attribute_name . '-' . $term->slug); ?>">
                                            <?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <button type="submit" value="apply" class="button" name="filteraction" >Apply Filters</button> 
                </form>
            <?php
        }
        function status($filters) {
            if (isset($_GET['filteraction'])) {
                if ($_GET['filteraction'] == 'apply') {
                    echo 'Filters Applied';
                } else {
                    echo 'Invalid action';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Choose a filter:';
            }
        }

        function checked($term, $filter) {
            $arr_name = isset($_GET[$filter->attribute_name]) ? $_GET[$filter->attribute_name] : [];
            $check = in_array($term->slug, $arr_name);
            $checked = checked( $check, true );
            return $checked;
        }

        function get_filter_options() {
            $term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
            $checked_att_ids_raw = get_term_meta($term_id, 'checked_atts');
            $checked_att_ids = array_pop( $checked_att_ids_raw ) ?: [];
            $all_atts = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();

            $filteratt = [];
            foreach ( $checked_att_ids as $index=>$att_id ) {
                $filteratt[$index] = $all_atts['id:' . $checked_att_ids[$index]];
            }
            return $filteratt; 
        }
        function get_filter_att_val($values) {
            $term_names = get_terms( [
                'taxonomy'  => 'pa_' . $values->attribute_name, 
                'fields'    => 'all', 
            ] );
            return $term_names;
        }
        //Product Cat Edit page
        function taxonomy_edit_meta_field($term) {
            //getting term ID
            $term_id = $term->term_id;
            $all_atts = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
            $checked_att_ids_raw = get_term_meta($term_id, 'checked_atts');
            $checked_att_ids = array_pop( $checked_att_ids_raw ) ?: [];
            ?>
                <tr class="form-field">
                    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="att_list"><?php _e('Filter by Attribute', 'wh'); ?></label></th>
                    <td>
                        <div style="height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll; background-color: white; padding: 8px;">
                            <?php foreach( $all_atts as $key => $attribute ): ?>
                                <div style="display: block">
                                    <input 
                                        type=   "checkbox" 
                                        name=   "att_list_items[]" 
                                        id=     "<?php echo esc_attr($attribute->attribute_name); ?>"
                                        value=  "<?php echo esc_attr($attribute->attribute_id);?>"
                                        <?php checked( in_array( $attribute->attribute_id, $checked_att_ids ), true ) ?>
                                    >
                                    <label 
                                        for="<?php echo esc_attr($attribute->attribute_name); ?>" >
                                        <?php echo esc_attr($attribute->attribute_label); ?>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                        <p class="description">Please select which attributes you would like to filter from</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
        }
        function save_taxonomy_custom_meta($term_id) {
            $wh_meta_title = $_POST['att_list_items'];
            update_term_meta($term_id, 'checked_atts', $wh_meta_title);
        }
    }             
    ($ccon_catalog_filters = new Ccon_Catalog_Filters)->init();
}

I tried downloading a couple plugins that have similar functionality to take them apart and reference them, but they were pretty convoluted and didn't give me any ideas for direction.

Wrap your inputs with <form> elements and add submit buttons. If setup properly, you'll get query strings like ?att_list_items[]=50 in the URL when submitting. You can read these values from the URL with the $_GET global variable. Add these values to your WP_Query arguments to filter the results based on the user's input.

That was very helpful, and got me quite a bit further down the right track.  Now, I have the parameters I want to filter the query with in the URL and can access them via $_GET - but to actually apply that to a query, are there hooks I should be using, or should I overwrite the theme template file and create a my own loop?

Creating your own loop is how I would do it.

Why is resolving advice being provided as comments?
